# Xcode 10 not showing images and removes Auto layout constraints that was there on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode10

Here are the screenshots of my Xcode 10 storyboard vs Xcode 9 for the same project.

[image: Xcode 10 storyboard]

[image: Xcode 9 storyboard]

How can we fix that?

Comment: Xcode 10 is in beta so there are going to be a multitude of issues. I would suggest just waiting until the full release because you are playing with fire. If you refuse to do that, you will have to manually re-input all the images and add all the constraints again from scratch.

Comment: I expected it to be buggy but not to this extent. I am just testing it after all

Comment: Yeah I loaded it up and was getting memory leaks and a multitude of other issues on a project that is very polished. So I swiftly went back to 9.4

Comment: @CaseyWest it's still the same even after updating to the final version. 
any ideas?

Comment: How are the images referenced? Are they in `xcassets` or directly added to the target? The reason your constraints are invalid is that imageViews define their (implicit) size via `intrinsicContentSize` which of course cannot be determined when the image is missing...